# how to do an action with a gtk_message_dialog without buttons

Tags: c, modal-dialog, gtk, gtk3

```
GtkWidget *infoDialog = gtk_message_dialog_new(NULL, GTK_DIALOG_MODAL | GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT, GTK_MESSAGE_INFO ,GTK_BUTTONS_NONE, "Please wait...");
gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG (infoDialog));

/* do_something */

gtk_widget_destroy(infoDialog);
```

My problem with the above code is that the part `/* do_something */` is never reached. I tried also with:

```
GtkWidget *infoDialog = gtk_message_dialog_new(NULL, GTK_DIALOG_MODAL | GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT, GTK_MESSAGE_INFO ,GTK_BUTTONS_NONE, "Please wait...");
gint r = gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG (infoDialog)); 
gtk_dialog_response(GTK_DIALOG(infoDialog), GTK_RESPONSE_OK);
if(r == GTK_RESPONSE_OK){
/* do_something */
}
gtk_widget_destroy(infoDialog);
```

but also with this solution the `do_something` code is never reached.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

the call to `gtk_dialog_run()` blocks the program flow, because it is using a nested main loop; it's the equivalent of `gtk_main()`. `gtk_dialog_run()` returns the response id when the dialog is dismissed — either by clicking on one of the dialog buttons, or by closing it using the window controls.

since you don't use any button, the only way to dismiss the dialog you created is to close it explicitly using the window controls; that action generates a `GTK_RESPONSE_DELETE_EVENT` response.

if you want to show the dialog and keep the program flow, you can show the dialog and then close it when needed:

```
GtkWidget *dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new (...);

gtk_widget_show (dialog);

/* start a long running operation inside an idle handler,
 * or a timeout, or a thread, and at the end of the operation
 * call gtk_widget_destroy() on the dialog
 */
```

obviously, you need to return control to the main loop in order for the toolkit to actually show the dialog. you cannot simply call `show()`, do some operation, and call `destroy()` without returning control to the main loop: the user won't see the dialog at all.

to be fair, showing a dialog without buttons that only shows "Please wait..." is not a great example of GUI; you should use a `GtkInfoBar` widget, or a `GtkStatusbar`, to notify your users that a long running operation is in progress.

Comment: thanks a lot for the tip of using info_bar or statusbar :) i'm new to gtk so i don't know all these things :)
However now i'm using info_bar but it doesn't show up because i have to pass it to the main loop. How can i do this? Because this part of the program is outside the main, it is a separate function...

Comment: Using `while (gtk_events_pending()) gtk_main_iteration();` solve my problem :)

Comment: spinning the event loop manually is not recommended: it means you expose yourself to re-entrancy issues. you should schedule the operation you're masking through the dialog/infobar into the main loop with a timeout or an idle handlers: see g_timeout_add() and g_idle_add(). there's also the option to use a thread, and schedule the GUI updates at the end of the thread.

Comment: actually my program structure is: `main` create a GApplication and call a `g_callback` to a func called `activate` when the `active` signal is emitted. Inside the `activate` func i create the main, grid, buttons, ecc. From here if the user click the "enc" button, the function `do_enc` is called. It is inside the function `do_enc` that i want to show this information!